# I cannot add images to the canvas of my thumbnail image gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, canvas

I'm new to html and javascript. I am trying to add images to a canvas when clicked on by calling the image from the image gallery. I'm using the onclick method to my script and isn't working thus I am struggling. I've added my code below. Thank you for your help! The assignment ask...

Implement the imgOnClick(elmt) function so that it paints (to the canvas' drawImage() method) the image given by elmt. elmt will be an  tag object. The canvas has the id imgresult.

In the document ready function, have each of the thumbnail images set their click event to the imgOnClick() function.  I recommend you test this for one image before implementing it for the remaining images. Make sure you scale the image to a usable size.

```
   <pre> <code><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="memeory.css">
        <title>Meme-ory :: Javascript Meme Generator</title>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $( document ).ready(function() {
           $('.thumbnail').click(imgOnClick('img'){ 

           });


       });


        function imgOnClick('img') {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("imgresult");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var img = document.getElementById("closeenough");

        ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);

        };

            };

            function buttonOnClick() {

            };



        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>Meme-ory: Raging on in the Moonlight!</h1>
        </header>

        <main>


            <div id="controls">
                <form>
                    <label for="toptext">Top Text:</label>
                    <input id="toptext" type="text">

                    <label for="bottomtext">Bottom Text:</label>
                    <input id="bottomtext" type="text">

                    <input id="createMemeButton" type="button" value="Give me Meme!">
                </form>
            </div>

            <div id="imagegallery">
                <img class="thumbnail" id="closeenough" src="closeenough.png" alt="close enough">
                <img class="thumbnail" id="cutenessoverload" src="cutenessoverload.png" alt="cuteness overload">
                <img class="thumbnail" id="deskflip" src="deskflip.png" alt="deskflip">
                <img class="thumbnail" id="lol" src="lol.png" alt="LOL">
                <img class="thumbnail" id="trollface" src="trollface.png" alt="troll face">
            </div>

            <div id="memeresult">
                <canvas id="imgresult">
                </canvas>
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add your html also.

Comment: updated the html

Comment: 2 Questions:

1. Are you getting any errors in your console?
2. If you're using jQuery, why aren't you using the jQuery methods for event listeners?

Comment: Sorry I am not well versed with jquery methods but The console error is saying "ErrorNotification.js:122 Cannot find context with specified id"

Answer (score 0):

If you try to select an element in a page, you can only do so when it has been created. You cannot select it BEFORE its existence. In this case you try to select a canvas and an image in the HEAD of you page, but these elements are only defined later on in your body.

There are two simple fixes:

Either you move your script code to the end of the page (just before `</body>`), or you include the code in the `$( document ).ready(function() {` block, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    window.onclick = function imgOnClick(e) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("imgresult");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var img = document.getElementById("closeenough");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    };
});
```

Both ways ensure that you try to select the elements when they have been created.

Comment: I tried it both ways that you described but I still wasn't able to load the image on the canvas.

Comment: Try checking your console for errors. Also notice that I changed imgOnClick('img'){  to imgOnClick(e) {